# how to get users from sharepoint user profile db using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

i just want to know: Is there any way to get a SharePoint user using JavaScript/jQuery from default sharepoint-2010 user profile DB?

My requirement is to form an array of all SharePoint site users (user name) and use this array in a java function (that run behind the page at client side ) as a data source for a SPServices function.

Please provide any feasible solution or any other approach for building the array for JavaScript.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

1. Use client object model (OM) for ECMAScript:

   - [Get all users and groups client object model sharepoint 2010](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/22/get-all-users-and-groups-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/)
   - [SharePoint 2010: Client Object Model for JavaScript (ECMAScript)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60348/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-for-JavaScript.aspx)

     The first article explains how to retrieve information about SharePoint users using OM and the second one shows how to use OM from JavaScript - you have to combine appropriate pieces of code.
2. Call appropriate method from the [**UserGroup** service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcusergroup.usergroup.aspx) (e.g. `GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb` or `GetUserCollection`) using jQuery:

   - [Calling the SharePoint Web Services with jQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx)
   - [Consuming WCF / ASMX / REST service using jQuery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59551/Consuming-a-WCF-ASMX-REST-Service-using-jQuery)
   - [Calling WCF Service using jQuery in Sharepoint Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anweshi/archive/2010/11/30/calling-wcf-service-using-jquery-in-sharepoint-applications.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Using SPServices from codeplex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function() {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName: "User Information List",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                        "</ViewFields>",
        completefunc: AttachMembersAutoComplete
    });
});
function AttachMembersAutoComplete(xmlResponse) {
    var domElementArray = $( "[nodeName=z:row]", xmlResponse.responseXML );

    var dataMap = domElementArray.map(function() {
        return {
            value: $(this).attr('ows_Title'),
        };
    });

    var data = dataMap.get();

    $("input#inputMembersAutoComplete").autocomplete({
        source: data,
        select: function(e, ui){
            var tmpHTML = ui.item['value'];
            $("#person_info").html(tmpHTML);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```